# Django logging in error- log in form does not log user in

Tags: django, authentication

When I try to log in as a user I can enter the username and password into the form and it continues to the next page, but it doesn't actually sign the user in. Where is my issue?

```
login.html file:
{% extends 'teammanager/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
   <form action="/profile/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using `url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'core/login.html'}, name='login'),` in urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action url is wrong.

The url that goes there should be empty, like this

```
<form method="post">
```

Action is url that data gets sent to, meaning you shouldn't be sending login information to profile but login url.
If you want to redirect the user after login to an url you need to set

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'core:home'
```

In the settings file, here I am redirecting user to namespace core and url named home.